# How to deal with nested arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print a nested list with `<ul><li>` structure but first, I need to order my data correctly. I'm trying to do that using multidimensional arrays, but I think I need some recursive code.
Actually i'm doing this:

```
function array_key_exists_recursive(array $arr, $key) {
if (array_key_exists($key, $arr)) {
    return true;
}
foreach ($arr as $element) {
    if (is_array($element)) {
        if (array_key_exists_recursive($element, $key)) {
            return true;
        }
    }  
}
return false;
}

$tags = array();
            foreach($gallery as $gg){
                $ftg = $gg['ftag']; //father category
                $tg = $gg['tag']; //category
                    if(array_key_exists($ftg , $tags)) {
                        if(!in_array($tg, $tags[$ftg])) {
                            $tags[$ftg][$tg] = null;
                        }
                    }
                    else { 
                        if(array_key_exists_recursive($tags, $ftg)) {
                            foreach($tags as $t=>$v) {
                                if(array_key_exists($ftg, $v)) {
                                    $tags[$t][$ftg]= $tg;
                                }; 
                            }
                        }
                        else $tags[$ftg][$tg] = null;
                    }
                }
```

Obviously that work only with 2nd level data structures and is different from what i need.. Someone knows how to make this code work?

Update: sorry for not adding the data array, i'm posting a little example here:

```
$gallery = array (
    '0' => array (
            'post-id' => 2,
            'id' => 711,
            'url' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/WhatsApp-Video-2019-10-11-at-09.42.44.mp4',
            'type' => 'video',
            'album' => 'UNO',
            'ftag' => 'Prova',
            'tag' => 'Categoria di Prova',
            'date' => '12/14/19'
        ),

    '1' => array (
            'post-id' => 2,
            'id' => 341,
            'url' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/VID-20180925-WA0025.mp4',
            'type' => 'video',
            'album' => 'DUE',
            'ftag' => 'Prova',
            'tag' => 'Categoria dei Video',
            'date' => '07/13/19'
        ),

    '2' => array (
            'post-id' => 2,
            'id' => 614,
            'url' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2-10-scaled.jpg',
            'type' => 'image',
            'album' => 'TRE',
            'ftag' => 'Foto',
            'tag' => 'Categoria delle foto',
            'date' => '12/09/19',
            'thumb' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/thumb_400_2-10-scaled.jpg'
        ),

    '3' => array (
            'post-id' => 2,
            'id' => 736,
            'url' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/iconfinder_camera-shutter_353402.png',
            'type' => 'image',
            'album' => 'QUATTRO',
            'ftag' => 'Categoria delle foto',
            'tag' => 'Categoria delle icone',
            'date' => '01/29/20',
            'thumb' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/thumb_400_iconfinder_camera-shutter_353402.png'
        ),

    '4' => array
        (
            'post-id' => 2,
            'id' => 744,
            'url' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/DSC_0102-scaled.jpg',
            'type' => 'image',
            'album' => 'Titolo dell album',
            'ftag' => 'Categoria delle icone',
            'tag' => 'Terzo livello',
            'date' => '02/03/20',
            'thumb' => 'http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/thumb_400_DSC_0102-scaled.jpg'
        )
);
```

Now, from this i have to make an array of only categories (ftag and tag) where ftag is the father category and tag is the category.. I thought that i could order in "levels" with some sort of nested arrays, to print the data later with a structure like:

```
<ul>
    <li>Category</li>
    <li>Category
        <ul>
            <li>Subcategory</li>
            <li>Subcategory
                <ul>
                    <li>3rd Level</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You may want to update your question with the array itself with some data and structure, and the desired output.

Comment: How would you got about this without data array?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I'm sorry, i retrieve my $gallery array from other functions and it is a little too big to post so i  added a little example

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand your code but let's say you have a list of categories with a list of products inside each category.  A good structure for the array would be something like this:

```
$categories = array(
   array(
      'name' => 'Category 1',
      'products' => array(
         array('name' => 'Product 1'),
         array('name' => 'Product 2'),
      ),
   ),
   array(
      'name' => 'Category 2',
      'products' => array(
         array('name' => 'Product 3'),
         array('name' => 'Product 4'),
         array('name' => 'Product 5'),
      ),
   ),
);
```

This creates a list of two categories: category 1 and category 2.  Category 1 has 2 products in it, category 2 has 3 products.

Now we can loop around them and build a nested HTML list:

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
      <li>
         <?php print $category['name']; ?>
         <ul>
            <?php foreach ($category['products'] as $product) : ?>
               <li><?php print $product['name']; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
         </ul>
      </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I know that my code could be a little unclear and i'm sorry for that. This is part of a "gallery" that i'm doing as an addon for Elementor (a wordpress plugin).. unfortunately, i cannot do much on the $gallery array because on the "front-end" part, where the user add images and videos, there's no possiblity of making a nested structure for categories.. The only thing i could do is insert a father category and a child category, and nest them later

Comment: @nico_b am I right in thinking that some posts wouldn't have a father category?

Comment: Nope, there will always be a father category set by default in other code.. The child category is not always present instead

Comment: So you have a list of the top-level categories?  I'm assuming one is "Prova" and the other is "Foto" ?

Comment: Exactly, Prova and Foto are the top level categories, then we've the child categories and child have child.. To nest them, i use to name father category with the same name of the child of the previous level.. I know it's a bit unclear but i have to do this unfortunately..

Comment: Been here a hundred times with WordPress.  Will update answer shortly with a potential solution.. might take a while.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i'm really out of ideas